# Matching characters between 2 strings

Tags: python, string, loops, while-loop

I've been having issues with this piece of code. It seems that my understanding of while loops and indentation in Python is still incomplete.

In the code below, I'm supposed to compare two statements. If the characters in the second (search) statement are in the first (target) statement, then the result should be "True". Else, print "False".

```
x = "I am a horse."
y = "a r"
```

- `targetn` refers to the index in target string
- `searchn` refers to the index in search string
- `letter` refers to characters in target string
- `word` refers to characters in search string

```python
def search_in_string(search, target):
    targetn = 0
    searchn = 0
    while (targetn + 1) != len(target):
        letter = target[targetn]
        word = search[searchn]
        if word == letter:
            targetn = targetn + 1
            searchn = searchn + 1
        if word != letter:        
            targetn = targetn + 1   
    if (searchn + 1) == len(searchn):
        return True
    else: 
        return False

print search_in_string(y, x)
```

Running the code in Python, I get index errors as `searchn` goes out of range. I would appreciate:

1. What's wrong with the code and;
2. Where my understanding of indentations and while loops is incomplete.

Comment: Could you please clarify exactly what this function is *supposed* to do? I think your problem is with the logic, not the indentation, but I'm not sure what you're going for. (My best guess is that it's supposed to return `True` if and only if `target` is a substring of `search`.)

Comment: To me, your indentation looks fine. I completely agree with Zack, your logic seems a bit off. But we don't know what this function supposed to do. What is the expected input and output?

Comment: Thanks, I've made edits to clarify - yes, the code is supposed to return True or False at the end.

Answer (score 1):

> "**1. What's wrong with the code**"

**Typo in line 12**: it should be `len(search)` instead of `len(searchn)`.

**Off-by-one errors**: if index==len(array) then it is already off the end. Remove `+ 1` in all index tests.

**Remaining bug in line 4**: test both `targetn` and `searchn` in the while condition. Depending on the data in the strings, either one can hit the end first. (Moving the final searchn test to inside the loop, that luk32 suggests, also fixes this bug, but not for the special cases when search is empty or longer than target.)

> "**2. Where my understanding of indentations and while loops is incomplete.**"

No, but maybe lists and array indexes.

But more important, naming of function and variables are not very clear, and the style of the code looks very much like C.

**Naming**

In the current code (with the bug fixes) try this:

- change the function name `search_in_string` to `is_subsequence`
- change variable name `search` to `partial`
- change variable name `target` to `full`
- likewise change the index variables to `ipart` and `ifull` or similar
- remove the variables `letter` and `word` completely
- replace `letter` with `full[ifull]` and `word` with `partial[ipart]` in the tests

Isn't it clearer now?

Here I have also replaced the complementary second `if` test with an obvious `else`:

```
def is_subsequence(partial, full):
    ifull = 0
    ipart = 0
    while ifull != len(full) and ipart != len(partial):
        if partial[ipart] == full[ifull]:
            ifull = ifull + 1
            ipart = ipart + 1
        else:
            ifull = ifull + 1
    if ipart == len(partial):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

**Style**

The program style still looks like C with arrays, explicit loops, and elaborate manipulation of indexes. Here is an opportunity for you to learn about a coding style called "pythonic". See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58968/what-defines-pythonian-or-pythonic and a couple of the links there.

I'd say gnibbler's answer is pythonic, but may be hard to grasp if you don't know iterators and list comprehension. Here is another somewhat pythonic solution, that I hope is a little easier to read. You need to know about array slices, however.

```
def is_subsequence(partial,full):
    for char in full:
        if partial.startswith(char):
            partial = partial[1:]
    return len(partial) == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

*With out getting into logic of the code.*

**EDIT**: Ok there is an error in intendation on the `if` guard.
Zero-length arguments will also be a problem, though.

```
x = "I am a horse."
y = "a r"

def search_in_string(search, target):
    targetn = 0
    searchn = 0
    while (targetn + 1) != len(target):
        letter = target[targetn]
        word = search[searchn]
        if word == letter:
            targetn = targetn + 1
            searchn = searchn + 1
        if word != letter:        
            targetn = targetn + 1   
    #This will get executed AFTER the WHILE loop
    if (searchn + 1) == len(search):
        return True
    else: 
        return False

print(search_in_string(x,y))
```

Working code:

```
def search_in_string(search, target):
    targetn = 0
    searchn = 0
    while (targetn + 1) != len(target):
        letter = target[targetn]
        word = search[searchn]
        if word == letter:
            targetn = targetn + 1
            searchn = searchn + 1
        if word != letter:        
            targetn = targetn + 1   
        #This will get executed WITHIN the WHILE loop
        if (searchn + 1) == len(search):
            return True
        else: 
            return False
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an easier way to write your function

```
def search_in_string(search, target):
    iter_t = iter(target)
    return all(c in iter_t for c in search)
```

eg:

```
>>> search_in_string("a r", "I am a horse.")
True
>>> search_in_string("a re", "I am a horse.")
True
>>> search_in_string("a er", "I am a horse.")
False
```